# tomcat session replication delay in non-sticky cluster

Tags: session, tomcat7

I am using tomcat 7.0.47 in a clustered environment with non-sticky load-balancer.  Session are stored in postgres database through PersistentManager with the following settings:

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager"
                     distributable="true"
                     processExpiresFrequency="1"
                     saveOnRestart="true"
                     maxActiveSessions="-1"
                     minIdleSwap="0"
                     maxIdleSwap="0"
                     maxIdleBackup="0">
```

I have notice that it takes anywhere between 3 to 5 seconds for newly created session to be persisted to the database.  Currently, I have introduced an artificial delay after the session creation event to allow session to be available for other servers.

Obviously, this is not ideal. Has anyone encounter this issue and can suggest a fix to this?  Changing load-balancer to sticky is not an option.